# Why is “wird” used in “ob unser Baby ein Junge oder ein Mädchen wird”?

Tags: word-choice, tense

From Rosetta Stone:

> Wir werden zum Arzt gehen, um herauszufinden, ob unser Baby ein Junge
> oder ein Mädchen **wird**.

Would it make sense if it was changed to one of the following?

> Wir werden zum Arzt gehen, um herauszufinden, ob unser Baby ein Junge oder ein Mädchen **ist**.
>
> Wir werden zum Arzt gehen, um herauszufinden, ob unser Baby ein Junge oder ein Mädchen **sein wird**.

Is there a specific rule that explains the use of *werden?*

Comment: All three options are fine, but have a different focus.

Comment: It all depends on your definition of a baby vs. a fetus still with the mother.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All three are correct. There is little to no difference in meaning, unless we start nit-picking:

> ... ein Mädchen ist

is simply present tense ("... is a girl"). This is the most logical thing to say, since it accepts that the unborn already is a human being.

> ...ein Mädchen sein wird

is future I and the same as "... will be a girl" in English.

> ...es ein Mädchen wird

Here, "wird" is to be translated as "becomes", implying that the baby is neither boy nor girl until born, or incomplete. It is what I would call the traditional way to say it - not a grammatical rule, but an established phrase in everyday speech.

Answer (score 0):

"Sein wird" is unnecessarily redundant; "ist" would work, but I imagine that there were pedagogical reasons involved in this choice -- they probably wanted to give the student an opportunity to practice "werden."

If we change the sentence just a bit, to

> I hope the birth goes well and the baby is healthy

then "wird" is a more obvious best choice.  Hope that helps!